# What do we do about duplicates of questions from other SE sites?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

This question has an almost exact duplicate on hermenuetics SE. But the asker, of course didn't know that that question existed because it doesn't show up as a potential duplicate, and unless you're active on both sites, you wouldn't realize that. What should we do about questions like this? That particular question on this site already has an answer.

I realize the set of questions that are actually on-topic for two sites is small, but we don't want to be duplicating content of another SE site, do we?

Comment: This issue was just opened by somebody else, I think one meta post should work to clarify the issue for now.

Comment: Yeah, it is. I didn't think to search before posting. Sometimes I'm a little careless on meta.